# Change datetime to date with month name in word

Tags: php

I am new to Stack Overflow. So please guide me if my question is not clear to you.

```
I have a datetime such as 2016-10-08 11:02:55. 
I need to convert it into like this 8 OCT 2016.
```

Do anybody have any idea how could i get it in this format. This has to be do in PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: `2016-10-08 11:02:55` isn't timestamp. That is datetime

Comment: yes thanks @Mohammad i have updated question . Thanks

Comment: Let me guide you: you should read [ask] and [mcve]. It's helpful and let you understand how to ask questions. Now this requires editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert target string to time and use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert time to formated date. Also [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) convert all character to uppercase.

```
$x = "2016-10-08 11:02:55";
echo strtoupper(date("j M Y",strtotime($x)));
```

**Result:**

```
8 OCT 2016
```

**Working [DEMO](https://repl.it/EBYR/0)**

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up vote your solution. But it is absolute solution . Thanks. I appreciate.

Comment: Strange. You are the one who posted the question so you can just click the `check` icon to mark it as SOLVED.

Comment: Yes i have upvoted your solution. But my vote will make any difference once i got minimum 15 reputation.

Comment: Upvote is different from marking it as solved. There is check button below the downvote. Click it to mark it as SOLVED and help the others next time if they found this.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about PHP is that there is usually more than one way to obtain the desired result and that principle holds true in this case, too.  You could also write the following code:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2016-10-08 11:02:55');
echo strtoupper($date->format('j M Y'));
```

See live code [here](https://3v4l.org/kk8XC).

The advantage of this solution is that you pass the string as a parameter to initialize a new DateTime object.  You can use that object to then specify the date format.  Lastly, I use strtouppe() to have the month name in all caps.

In fairness, though, the Manual says that this object's format method is limited, as follows:

> This method does not use locales. All output is in English.

PHP provides the DateTime class with another method which one may statically invoke in order to instantiate a DateTime object.  If you wish, you may provide time zone information to the method.  So, another way to code a solution is as follows:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d g:i:s', "2016-10-08 11:02:55");
echo strtoupper( $date->format('j M Y') );
```

See live code [here](https://3v4l.org/af83V).